# Service Worker and TYPO3

Tags: typo3, service-worker, web-push, typo3-8.x

I want to add push notifications to my TYPO3 extension. For this is want to use a service worker like [Service Worker Web Push](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/).

I have done the example and all works great! But when I integrate my main.js to my template a "Dom Exception 18" is thrown.

Here is my main.js, which is exactly the same like in the example:

```
'use strict';

const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BMwhXLRMix27LxWMJYAGpWHbAtdFpqbmd6bTf_V0JvJ5baSqevTlzB5gSbx_nC6hQRpbnScdrfe3VzRCxX4rCO4';

const pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-btn');

let isSubscribed = false;
let swRegistration = null;

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');

  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}

function updateBtn() {
  if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);
    return;
  }

  if (isSubscribed) {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
  } else {
    pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
  }

  pushButton.disabled = false;
}

function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
  // TODO: Send subscription to application server

  const subscriptionJson = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-json');
  const subscriptionDetails =
    document.querySelector('.js-subscription-details');

  if (subscription) {
    subscriptionJson.textContent = JSON.stringify(subscription);
    subscriptionDetails.classList.remove('is-invisible');
  } else {
    subscriptionDetails.classList.add('is-invisible');
  }
}

function subscribeUser() {
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
  })
  .then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('User is subscribed.');

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

    isSubscribed = true;

    updateBtn();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
    updateBtn();
  });
}

function unsubscribeUser() {
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    if (subscription) {
      return subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
  })
  .then(function() {
    updateSubscriptionOnServer(null);

    console.log('User is unsubscribed.');
    isSubscribed = false;

    updateBtn();
  });
}

function initialiseUI() {
  pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    pushButton.disabled = true;
    if (isSubscribed) {
      unsubscribeUser();
    } else {
      subscribeUser();
    }
  });

  // Set the initial subscription value
  swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

    if (isSubscribed) {
      console.log('User IS subscribed.');
    } else {
      console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
    }

    updateBtn();
  });
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(function(swReg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

    swRegistration = swReg;
    initialiseUI();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {

    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}
```

I have checked if the worker can be loaded with:

```
$.get('sw.js').done(function(){
  console.log.('file found')})
```

I have also checked all paths multiple times and they are correct.

Dose anyone has a idea why I get the following Error:

> Service Worker Error DOMException [SecurityError: "The operation is
>   insecure."
>       code: 18

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? HTTP can't be used with service workers

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try it with HTTPS. Is a self signed certificate enough?

Comment: No, you must use a real certificate or `localhost` (which doesn't require SSL for service workers). BTW have you considered using a service like Pushpad instead of building everything from scratch?